# pause video in phonegap(android) while going on homescreen

Tags: javascript, cordova

I  m using html5 video plugin https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video for playing videos on android. I need to pause video while i'm going to home screen or app is going in background.  Any Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a handler to the pause event to perform an action before the app is put into the background: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

However, at a brief glance, it doesn't look like the player you are using provides functionality to pause or stop playback in its API.

Comment: do u know any other player??

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know of any that allow you to pause/resume playback, but you can try searching for one